# Facebook Login in Google App Engine Application (php)

Tags: php, facebook, google-app-engine

Currently, users of my appengine application can use their google account to login to the site. I want to allow users to login using their facebook account. How to do this?

Comment: First of all, go and read this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/
and you can use OpenId also(Search Internet for tutorial)
if you face any problem , while implementing it, then you should ask it over here...

Comment: Server side facebook integration requires curl on gae - which is not available at the moment. I am curious, if there is another way of doing this. Maybe using an external login provider with callback urls.

Comment: curl is now available, either as real curl or a facade that translates to urlfetch calls. Real curl is available only for projects with billing enabled. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_cURL_support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Download that branch of SDS: https://github.com/camfitz/facebook-php-sdk;

2) Create an Application on facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/ > Apps > Create New Application;

3) Edit the example.php downloaded, and change the 'appId' and 'secret' to the data in you facebook application Dashboard page;
));

4) Read the "Authentication and authorization" in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/ and adjust the example code if needed.

5) Run it and VOILA!

Comment: Server side facebook integration requires curl on gae - which is not available at the moment.